# Thymeleaf change suffix / prefix for StringTemplateResolver?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I change the settings that my variables need to have [[${name}]] ?
I want to change it to {{name}} ?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
  
        String templateString = "<p>Hello, [[${name}]]!</p>";

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("name", "John Doe");

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        templateEngine.process(templateString, context, stringWriter);

        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }

}
```